# How to load an XML document using a relative path in VB.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net

In VB.net when loading in XML documents using System.Xml.Xmldocument is there a way that I can specify a relative path to the file?

```
path = "file.xml"
xmld.Load(path)
```

The XML doc I'm trying to load is in the same directory as the VB class. But I'm having trouble accessing it without using a full path to the XML doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import only System.Xml and try...

```
Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
 xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("Divide.xml"))
```

Divide.xml will obviously be replaced by your xml file's name.
From MSDN, Server.MapPath is as follows..

> Specifies the relative or virtual path
>   to map to a physical directory. If
>   Path starts with either a forward (/)
>   or backward slash (), the  MapPath
>   method returns a path as if Path were
>   a full, virtual path. If Path doesn't
>   start with a slash, the  MapPath
>   method returns a path relative to the
>   directory of the .asp file being
>   processed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.StartupPath()
```

will point to the executing location of the application. If the final build location for your XML file will be in a directory different than this, I recommend creating a small file manager class that will point to the proper location of the file. That way you can simply call:

```
xmlDoc.Load(myFileMan.FilePath())
```

and let the manager resolve the proper path based on a debug/release build and any other potential mitigating factors on it.

Comment: The Application.StartupPath() property is specific to WinForms, no?

Comment: True, just as Server.MapPath is specific to WebForms. Your question really didn't indicate which type of app you were using, so I wanted to toss the alternative in there to let you know.

Comment: Good call!  I forgot that Server.MapPath was webforms inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

If in SSIS then try this:

```
'Loading an Xml File from VB'

 Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
 xmlDoc.Load("C:\Test\sample.xml")
```